# json_encode using PHP skips html tags

Tags: php, html, json, tags

I want to convert php string or array in Json so I used json_encode. but as my string is html content, html tags are skipped with json convert.

Please check below code

```
$test = array('name' => 'Header Images','template' => '{{#each images}}<span>{{image_url}}</span>{{/each}}');
print_r(json_encode($test,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

Result :

```
{"name":"Header Images","template":"{{#each images}}{{image_url}}<\/span>{{\/each}}"}
```

Here  tag is skipped. I also used json_encode without JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE, but no changes.

Answer (score 1):

HTML tags are a valid content for JSON. What happened here is that your browser interpreted the tags as tags (because you just output the JSON into the browser).

If you change your code to `print_r(htmlspecialchars(json_encode($test,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)));`, you will see that tags are indeed included in your JSON (or alternatively you can *View Source* in your browser and see that your tags are there).

Comment: Thank you for Your reply. I have used "`&lt;`" and "`&gt;`" to display html brackets. and It works as I wish.
Here is the changed code : $test = array('name' => 'Header Images','template' => '{{#each images}}`&lt;`span`&gt;`{{image_url}}`&lt;`/span`&gt;`{{/each}}');

Answer (score 0):

Your browser hides all tags. use htmlentities() to see all tags.

```
$test = array('name' => 'Header Images','template' => '{{#each images}}<span>{{image_url}}</span>{{/each}}');
$test = json_encode($test);
print_r(htmlentities($test));
```

Result:

```
{"name":"Header Images","template":"{{#each images}}<span>{{image_url}}<\/span>{{\/each}}"}
```